# M2.2 - Advanced Search - Search Multiple SKUs?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, advanced-search

I am trying to use Magento's Advanced search in an effort to return multiple SKUs.

I have tried methods via the frontend/url like searching using quotes, +, & and more..

```
"SKU1""SKU2"
SKU1&SKU2
SKU1+SKU2
etc.
```

but they always tend to return either no result or the first SKU and nothing more. Is there a way to change the advanced search formula (and only the advanced search version as we have an extension working perfectly for regular use, we are just attempting to use the advanced search as another means to get this side necessity accomplished)

Be it from the backend editing within /vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/ or anywhere else? Surely there should be a possible/relatively easy solution.

**UPDATE EDITS:**

Trying to use the URL directly by replacing SKU1 and SKU2 with proper sku's doesn't work and throws the below error. Trying to use the advanced search form and searching with either a space between the SKUs or a comma just throws the error of not finding any matches.

The error at this time that I am receiving is;

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/core/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/result.phtml on line 39
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Array to string...', '/home/location...', 39, Array)
#1 /app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/core/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/result.phtml(39): implode(',', Array)
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/location...')
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Result), '/home/location...', Array)
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/location...')
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('catalogsearch_a...')
#8 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('catalogsearch_a...')
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('catalogsearch_a...')
#10 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#11 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#12 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content')
#13 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content.wr...')
#14 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content.wr...')
#15 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content.wr...')
#16 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#17 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main')
#19 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns_schedul...')
#20 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns_schedul...')
#21 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns_schedul...')
#22 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns_schedul...')
#23 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns_schedul...')
#24 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns_schedul...')
#25 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#26 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#27 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns')
#28 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content_sc...')
#29 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content_sc...')
#30 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content_sc...')
#31 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#32 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#33 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content')
#34 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#35 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#36 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#37 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#38 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#39 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#40 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#41 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#42 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#43 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#44 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#45 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#46 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#47 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#48 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#49 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#50 /vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(221): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#51 /vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Controller/Advanced/Result.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\View->renderLayout()
#52 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result->execute()
#53 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#54 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#55 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#56 /generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Controller/Advanced/Result/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#57 /vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#58 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#59 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#60 /vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#61 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#62 /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#63 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#64 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#65 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#66 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#67 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#68 /index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#69 {main}
```

While having the code as is;
/app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/core/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/result.phtml

```
<div class="search summary">
    <?php foreach (['left', 'right'] as $side): ?>
        <?php if (@$searchCriterias[$side]): ?>
            <ul class="items">
                <?php foreach ($searchCriterias[$side] as $criteria): ?>

    <?php $criteria['value'] = is_array($criteria['value']) ? implode(",",$criteria['value']) : $criteria['value']; ?>

                    <li class="item"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($criteria['name'])) ?>:</strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($criteria['value']) ?></li>

    <script>console.log('testing if works');</script>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Using the Advanced Search page (/catalogsearch/advanced/) and searching shows the message in the console so it's loading it, but shows incorrectly in that it isn't seeing the separate SKUs. However when trying to use the exact URL and replacing SKU1 with SKU2 is when the error seems to come.

I am using Magento CE 2.2.4 for clarity.

**EDIT 2:**

Success! Kind of. :) So the below string will work and supply the three requested SKUs;

```
https://example.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?sku[in][]=SKU1&sku[in][]=SKU2&sku[in][]=SKU3
```

What I did (and had to remove to get there);

What works now;

```
<div class="search summary">
    <?php foreach (['left', 'right'] as $side): ?>
        <?php if (@$searchCriterias[$side]): ?>
            <ul class="items">
                <?php foreach ($searchCriterias[$side] as $criteria): ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

What was removed;

```
<li class="item"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($criteria['name'])) ?>:</strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($criteria['value']) ?></li>
```

Which was inside the foreach loop. Not sure if this was ideal, but I gave it a shot and removing so got everything working correct. I knew the criteria was correct because doing a `print_r($criteria['value']);` would give:

```
Array
(
    [in] => Array
        (
            [0] => SKU1
            [1] => SKU2
            [2] => SKU3
        )

)
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it either. Searching for Order Numbers in this format seems to work `"4567","1234"`. But not Skus in the Catalog.

Comment: @Craig Take a look at the below answer, works well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the sku attribute is configured to provide wildcard searches, that means that the query for the value of this field is  build in the way `sku LIKE '%[FIELD_VALUE]%'`.

So if you want to use another type of search (i.e. in your case one solution would be to use `IN (FIELD_VALUE1, FIELD_VALUE2)` insetad of `sku LIKE '%[FIELD_VALUE]%'`) you have first of all change the filter for the sku field. Then you can either change the form for advanced search (to provide an array for the values) or manipulate the input using a plugin before the `execute` method in controller `Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result` and split the input to get the needed array.

**change of search configuration:**

1. Copy `vendor/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/search_request.xml` into the `etc` directory of your module (i.e. `/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/`)
2. Change the filter for the `sku` attribute from `wildcardFilter` to `termFilter`
3. change the version of your module and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

With this changes done you can use an array for `sku` parameter with the key `in` (which defines the type of the query) and multiple values for skus.
Just call http://yourmagentohost/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?sku[]=SKU1&sku[]=SKU2 and will get the result.

There is also a small issue in the `result.phtml` template, where the usage of an array for the sku causes an error because a string is expected, you just have to do something like implode there,
for example this line in the `serachCriterias` loop would do it:

```
<?php $criteria['value'] = is_array($criteria['value']) ? implode(",",$criteria['value']) : $criteria['value']; ?>
```

To overwrite the template you need to copy the original template from `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/result.phtml` into your theme directory `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/result.phtml`

Now you can change the logic in the form to create this kind of requests for your sku and you're done.

If you don't want to change the form, you can use a plugin before the `execute` method in controller `Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result` like the following:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class AdvancedSearch
{
    protected $_context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context
        ){
        $this->_context = $context;   

    }
    public function beforeExecute(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result $subject)
    {
        $request = $this->_context->getRequest();
        $queryValue = $request->getQueryValue();
        if (isset($queryValue['sku'])){
            $queryValue['sku'] = explode(" ", $queryValue['sku']);
        }
        $request->setQueryValue($queryValue);
    }
}
```

With this changes you will be able to search for multiple skus spearated by space but you won't be able to search for parts of skus (i.e. LIKE queries). 
Setting the filter (e.g. wildcard filter if no list of skus is given) depending on your input would be more complicated, I guess.

Comment: Hey @helgeb, I tried the 3 steps but when trying a search with the context you displayed, I get the error: `Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/magento/framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/Filter/Builder/Wildcard.php on line 38` ... Any ideas?

Comment: That means that your `search_request.xml` either does not have the changes I have mentioned or is not loaded. The error is because of the wildcard filter which needs to be replaced in the configuration file. In the section `advanced_search_container` the filter for `sku_query_filter` needs to be `termFilter`

Comment: Great, so that issue is solved, however after placing the implode function inside the results.phtml, I am receiving this error: `Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /view/frontend/templates/advanced/result.phtml on line 40` ... I am placing the implode right after `<?php foreach ($searchCriterias[$side] as $criteria): ?>` ... should it be somewhere else?

Comment: that is the right place for the implode. Are you sure you have overwritten the template? The error message seems to be from the default template.

Comment: I was trying to copy the original search_request.xml over to my theme in: `/app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/core/Magento_CatalogSearch/etc/` but for whatever reason it wasn't seeing it / the changes I made. So I did the wildcard change in the default vendor section which worked (not ideal but just working with dev site right now anyways) thus I tried the same method with adding the implode onto the vendor section and go through the setup:upgrade, di:compile and static-content:deploy, however it is throwing that error. Any idea why the error inside the original vendor version?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the complete path for both - the xml file and the template. The xml file needs to be in the etc folder of your custom module not the theme folder, the template needs to be in `/app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/core/Magento_CatalogSearch/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/result.phtml` (I assume your theme folder is `/app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/core/`)

Comment: Thanks for the continued assistance! My mistake on the paths, I have that all situated out now, however still getting the same error: `/app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/core/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/result.phtml on line 39` where the relative lines are: `<?php foreach ($searchCriterias[$side] as $criteria): ?><?php $criteria['value'] = is_array($criteria['value']) ? implode(",",$criteria['value']) : $criteria['value']; ?><li class="item"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($criteria['name'])) ?>:</strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($criteria['value']) ?></li><?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: I edited the question with updates of what I have and what I'm presented with. Using M2.2.4, does anything stand out?

Comment: Edited the main post again, we have degrees of success, my only and most likely last question (thank you again) is if the proposed solution now is ideal, or if my kind of hacking it to work is not a good solution

Comment: Sorry, I have just checked the code again. You just have to change the query parameter for sku, I have updated the answer. You can skip the `[in]` key then the implode should work and the query will give you the result. Don't remove the code. So your url should be `sku[]=SKU1&sku[]=SKU2&sku[]=SKU3`

Comment: Works great now with everything put back and just removing the [in]. Thank you!

Comment: Great to here that, you're welcome